# have understood versus did understand

Tags: present-perfect

Is it possible to use this time with present perfect, as when we say "this time" it does indicate a very precise one off moment that will not happen again.
Imagine that many persons  tried to explain a problem but I did not understand it then a new person came and explained the problem in a different way then I said "**I have understood / did understand** this time!!!"

I think the first one is better but if this moment will not happen again may be past simple is better but I doubt

Answer (score 1):

"I understand this time."

"In the past, I understood that we did it this way."

Here is a [full list](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/understand.html).

---

Sorry I re-read your question.

"This time" in the sense that you're using it, "I understand this time!", implies that it's something that has "finally" happened, but could easily be used in other ways, "I understood the daily lesson this time, but I'm not sure if I will understand tomorrow's lesson."

Comment: you did not understand my question !

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: What I want to say by using present perfect it is that it took some time before I fully understood it